# WPF Dynamic resource reference

Tags: wpf, dynamicresource

HI

Am load a string xaml with DynamicResource assigned to a Background property. Is there a way to get the reference of the dynamic resource.

```
Background="{DynamicResource Color1}"
```

I want to get the resource reference assigned to a Dependency property at runtime
Pl help

Comment: Where is the DependencyProperty defined? On the same Window/UserControl?

Answer (score 1):

[Use FrameworkElement.FindResource Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx)

```
this.FindResource("Color1");
```

Comment: Sorry I have to rephrase the question.... I want to get the resource reference assigned to a Dependency property

Comment: you will get reference to the object that dependency property referenced, why you need exactly that reference?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the DependencyProperty defined? On the same Window/UserControl? If you simply want to bind to the value of a DependencyProperty you probably want to use regular {Binding ...} syntax instead.

**Example 1**: If you are binding to a dependency property on a particular control named *myControl* you can declare it like below.

```
Background="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=Color1}"
```

**Example 2**: If you don't want to rely on naming controls because it is so pasay in WPF and you are referencing a property defined on your Window you could do something like below.

```
Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Color1}"
```